# Python URL matching (Regex)

Tags: python, regex

I've tried to match a the below URL for a couple of hours and can't seem to figure it out and Im quite sure its not that difficult:

The URL can be this:

```
/course/lesson-one/
```

or it can also be:

```
/course/lesson-one/chapter-one/
```

What  I have is the following which matches the second URL:

```
/course/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/
```

What I want is for the second part to be optional but I can't figure it out the closest I got was the following:

```
/course/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/*([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/
```

But the above for some reason leaves out the last letter of the word for example if the URL is

```
/course/computers/
```

I end up with the string 'computer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `?` if you need optional parts.

```
/course/([a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z]*)/([a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z]*/)?
#                                                 ^
```

(Note that `[a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z]*`.)

Use an additional grouping `(?:…)` to exclude the `/` from the match, while allowing multiple elements to be optional at once:

```
/course/([a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z]*)/(?:([a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z]*)/)?
#                            ~~~                     ~^
```

---

Your 2nd regex swallows the last character, because:

```
  /course/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/*([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        this matches 'computer'  and this matches the 's'.
```

The second group in this regex required to match some alphabets with length 1 or more due to the `+`, so the 's' must belong there.

Comment: Ok thank you, it's the question mark that Im missing. Just glanced at the docs and its a one liner explains why I overlooked it!

Comment: The second regex you included above is exactly what I needed also thank you for explaining it real well +100. Thanks to everyone that contributed below.

Answer (score 1):

use a "?" after something to make it considered optional.

```
>>> r = r"/course/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)(/[A-Z[a-z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)?"
>>> s = "/course/lesson-one/chapter-one/"
>>> re.match(r, s).groups()
('lesson-one', '/chapter-one')
>>> s = "/course/computers/"
>>> re.match(r, s).groups()
('computers', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
'/course/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)(/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/)?'
```

This makes the second part optional and still matches each of the parts of the URL.

Note that the second part of the URL has two groups: one that matches `/chapter-one/` and one that matches `chapter-one`

```
>>> re.match('/course/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)(/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/)?', '/course/lesson-one/chapter-one/').groups()
('lesson-one', '/chapter-one/', 'chapter-one')
```

Similarly:

```
>>> re.match('/course/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)(/([a-zA-Z]+[-a-zA-Z]*)/)?', '/course/lesson-one/').groups()
('lesson-one', None, None)
```